# Canvas.toDataURL() returns a file without extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm converting an HTML canvas into a jpg when a save button is clicked. I use the code below:

```
$('#save').click(function(e){
    var canvas = $('#myCanvas')[0];
    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png","image/octet-stream");   
    window.location.href=image; // it will save locally
});
```

Unfortunately, I download file without any extension. What I want is when I click the download button, The browser must download file from the page with a file extension.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

@K3N's answer didn't work for me because as mentioned:

> Ideally you set the href before the click somehow.

I built on top of it and did this and it works great.

```
var btnSave = document.getElementById('btnSave');
btnSave.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var image = photo.toDataURL("image/png");
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.setAttribute('download', 'myFilename.png');
    anchor.setAttribute('href', image);
    anchor.click();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `#save` element is an anchor tag (`<a ...></a>`) you can do this:

```
$('#save').click(function(e){
    var canvas = $('#myCanvas')[0];
    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    $('#save').attr({
        'download': 'myFilename.png',  /// set filename
        'href'    : image              /// set data-uri
    });
});
```

Ideally you set the `href` before the click somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

for loading,you need to use:

```
document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
```

Comment: Thanks..but it redirects me to a new tab. Thanks anyway :)